# Read Data from URL on flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I developed a website using React, now I need to build some parts of the application, using flutter.
the problem is, when I launch the flutter app from my website, it's like a whole new app is opened and user needs to login again.
so this is my flutter app route, when it's launching: `https://MyGreateApp.com/#`
I just need to add some parameter like: `https://MyGreateApp.com/#/someId`
so I can recognize the user that opens this app.

so the question is, how can I read from path of the application and use it in my project,
or is there any better solution for this?

Comment: you need to use navigator2 in this case, [this](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/master/navigator2/demo1.dart) might help you